# How we can track mp4 videos on website using google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I wanted to know, how we can track mp4 videos on website using google analytics? The video is embeded version of youtube

Comment: I'm assuming you want to track the amount of views of a youtube video. Do you own the youtube account the video's are on? Or are they "random" videos?

Comment: I want to do a detailed tracking on website, like how many times people played, pause the video. Also how much percentage of video they played. (Yes, we own the youtube account where the videos are)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sumeetN This might be what youre looking for https://www.klipfolio.com/blog/connect-youtube-channel-google-analytics

Comment: @ErikBaars Thanks for the reply. I want to track the mp4 video of website not the youtube channel.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. Since tracking an embedded video requires interaction with the Youtube API, this is a programming question (although I would recommend switching to GTM and use its built-in Youtube tracking).